# How can I implement Swipe left and right to change data/views in swift IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swipe

I want to implement swipe gesture left right feature to change data views in swift 5. 
I have two viewControllers - `FeedsController` which contains tableview and list of all videos in it. In `FeedsController` if I click on comment button it moves to `commentViewController` and showing same video with with comments in details. 
Actually I want to implement Swipe gesture action on `commentViewController` so user can swipe left right even on detail comment page which is `commentViewController`.

Code for CommentViewController:

```
import UIKit
import FloatingPanel

final class CommentsViewController: UIViewController, CommentsViewInput, FloatingPanelControllerDelegate {
    var post: IContentPost!

    private var output: CommentsViewOutput?
    private var fpc: FloatingPanelController!
    private var mute: Bool {
        return ASVideoPlayerController.sharedVideoPlayer.mute
    }
    private weak var contentVC: BottomSheetInputView?
    private let router = Router()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()
        swipeGesture()

    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        fpc.removePanelFromParent(animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func dismissAction(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func swipeGesture(){
        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))
        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))

        leftSwipe.direction = .left
        rightSwipe.direction = .right

        view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
    }

    @objc func handleSwipes(_ sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if (sender.direction == .left)
        {
           print("Swipe Left")

        }

        if (sender.direction == .right)
        {
           print("Swipe Right")

        }
    }

    private func setup() {
        let presenter = CommentsPresentationModel(view: self, post: post)
        self.output = presenter
        setupTableView()
        setupPanel()
        output?.getComments() { [weak self] comments in
            guard let comments = comments else { return }
            self?.contentVC?.updateComments(with: comments)
        }
    }

    private func setupPanel() {
        fpc = FloatingPanelController()
        fpc.delegate = self // Optional
        let contentVC = router.bottomVC()
        contentVC.delegate = self
        self.contentVC = contentVC
        fpc.set(contentViewController: contentVC)
        fpc.track(scrollView: contentVC.tableView)
        fpc.addPanel(toParent: self)
    }

    private func setupTableView() {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView?.registerReusableCell(FeedContentTableViewCell.self)
    }

}

extension CommentsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: FeedContentTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath)
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.setup(with: post, mute: mute, needTopInset: false)
        return cell
    }

}

extension CommentsViewController: FeedContentCellDelegate {
    func likePressed(id: String) {
        output?.postLiked(postId:id)
    }

    func commentPressed(post: IContentPost) {
        fpc.show(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func sharePressed(id: String) {
        output?.postShared(postId: id)
        let text = "Hey! You gotta see that!  https://lols.link/share?\(id)"
        let textToShare = [text]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: textToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func mutePressed() {
        ASVideoPlayerController.sharedVideoPlayer.mute = !mute
    }
}

extension CommentsViewController: BottomSheetDelegate {
    func didCloseComments() {
        fpc.hide(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func didWriteComment(text: String) {

    }


}
```

**Update:**

Screenshot:

[image: FeedViewController]

[image: CommentsViewController]

Comment: Do you want to implement swipe to delete or something like that?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini no not to delete. Swipe to change records.

Comment: For your case, implement UIPageViewController to swipe left and right for viewing prev/next video comments.

Comment: @Mani But can you guide me how to achieve this? As I mentioned I have tableview which contains list of videos and below comment button just like insta type, once clicked it goes to comment - Detail page which has video on top and below all comments but I want change on swipe thing so user will not go back in same CommentViewController user can use swipe gesture.

Answer (score 2):

- Use 2 different functions to handle different swipe gestures
- Add following in `viewDidLoad()`

**up to Swift 4.0**

```
var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipedRight))
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right

var swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipedLeft))
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left

self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
```

**Swift 4.2 onwards**:
'UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection' has been renamed to 'UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction'

```
var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipedRight))
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right

var swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipedLeft))
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left

self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
```

- create two objc functions `swipedRight` and `swipedLeft`

```c
@objc func swipedRight()
{
    // Add your record changing code here
}

@objc func swipedLeft()
{
    // Add your record changing code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I am already doing this. I just need to know about record changing code :)

Comment: to change the records you have to load all items in collection view and then enable paging using flow layout .

Comment: @NayanDave If possible I can upload my project to github.

Comment: @ShivamParmar I am already using tableview even in commentViewController. Actually I am not getting an idea how to achieve.

Comment: can you send me screenshot of your screen and then explain ...!

Comment: @ShivamParmar I have added screenshots. Click on comments in FeedViewController will go to CommentViewController which has same video and comments and floating panel. I wanna add swipe gesture in CommentViewController

Comment: @ShivamParmar have you got an idea ?

Comment: @newbie there is no need to use Swipe Gesture in this case u will need only to put your details inside UICollectionViewCell.
 can u upload your code in Github and share the link i will help you do it :)

Comment: @AyoubNouri Thank you. Here is the link. 
https://github.com/MasamMahmood/VideoApp

Comment: @AyoubNouri have you got the link? Is it accessible?